# Help to make table of content

Tags: tables

I have been struggling to make a table of content to my thesis, can anyone help me with this? I was looking for a complete code where I could just put the names on the chapters and sections, but didnt manage to find. Help anyone?

Comment: Normally you just have to type `\tableofcontents`. LaTeX does the rest (compile twice).

Comment: @Bernard, so what do I write after that command? How do I make sections and so on? I am a beginner.. :)

Comment: @Bob: Consider reading the following: [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/5764)

Comment: For sections, you just type some thing like `\section{A section title}`, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

You can customise your table of contents however you want, but it's very easy to set the basic one. I added `\pagebreak`s so that you can see how it automatically refers to the pages where each section starts. I suggest that you keep the page break after the TOC, however, since sections starting at the middle of the page after the list of chapters is not very good, typographically speaking.

Remember that you need to compile twice each time you change something (concerning the sections, like adding a new one, etc).

Of course, since it's automatic, if you add other languages, the title `Contents` will switch to the main language you set (and so many other options will). For example, adding `\usepackage[french]{babel}` will change it to `Table des matières`, `[german]` will change it to `Inhaltsverzeichnis`, `[italian]` to `Indice`, and so on.

Here's a small preview of the 3 pages:

[image]

And here's the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

\section{My first chapter}

blabla

\pagebreak

\section{another chapter}

\end{document}
```